# Not able to connect sql server from java as a windows authentication on mac os x

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc

I am not able to connect sql server database in java from mac os x. It throws following error 
**java.sql.SQLException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.**

I have this in pom.xml

```
   <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
   <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

In application.yml

```
    driver-class-name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myDBServer/MyDB;domain=MyDOmain;integratedSecurity=true;
    username: username
```

Above solution works in windows but not on my mac os x.

I have tried following solutions:

```
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://dbServer:1433;DatabaseName=dbName;integratedSecurity=true;
    username: username
```

Comment: Is the Mac part of the Windows AD, and are you logged into the Mac as an AD user?

Comment: From SQL operation studio I can connect to database using windows authentication. So I guess mac is a part of windows AD

Comment: First, be clear about which JDBC driver you want to use. Your pom.xml refers to Microsoft's JDBC driver, but your application.yml is trying to use the jTDS driver. They are different things. Pick one.

Comment: @GordThompson edited question. Should be using jtds.